# Proof verification for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital

> Find the limit:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)}\ \  \text{for} \ \ a >0
> $$

Let:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_n = \frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)}\\
n\in\mathbb N
\end{cases}
$$

By definition of exponent we may rewrite $x_n$ as:
$$
x_n = \frac{a}{1+a}\cdot\frac{a}{1+a^2}\cdots\frac{a}{1+a^n}
$$

Since $a>0$:
$$
\forall a>0,k\in\mathbb N: \frac{a}{1+a^k} < 1
$$

Choose $q_n$ to be in the following form:
$$
q_n = \max\left\{\frac{a}{1+a}, \frac{a}{1+a^2}, \dots,\frac{a}{1+a^n}\right\}
$$

It follows that:
$$
x_n = \frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)} \le q^n_n
$$
Also $x_n > 0$. Now squeezing $x_n$ one may obtain:

$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n \le \lim_{n\to\infty} q^n_n = 0
$$
Thus:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)} = 0
$$

Have i missed something?

Comment: The logic is fine for me. Two notation details: when you define a sequence (like your $x_n$) don't forget the scope of $n$ ('for all $n\in\Bbb N'$, for example). And the equation after 'Since $a>0$' doesn't need any bracket.

Comment: The $q$, defined as the maximum over $\frac a{1+a},...,\frac a{1+a^n}$ depends on $n$, therefore it should be written as $q_n$. Then, it is not clear whether $q_n^n$ goes to zero. This is an issue.

Comment: One more detail: $x_n\le q_n$ (strict inequality may be false, and you don't need it).

Comment: Thank you for the notices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

As an alternative by ratio test

$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{a^{n+1}}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^{n+1})}\frac{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)}{a^n}=\frac{a}{1+a^{n+1}}$$

Comment: I find this approach much more elegant, thanks!

Comment: @roman Yes the good old ratio test seems very effective here :)

Comment: Nice application of the ratio test (+1).

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks a lot much appreciative from you! Regards

Answer (score 2):

Following your idea to apply the squeeze theorem, the proof becomes simpler if we note that $0\leq a<1$,
$$0\leq \frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)}\leq a^n\to 0$$
and for $a\geq 1$,
$$0\leq \frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2)\cdots(1+a^n)}\leq \frac{a^n}{2^n a^{n(n+1)/4}}\to 0$$
where we used the fact that $1+a^k\geq 2a^{k/2}.$